# Processing robbery case night time CCTV footage?

Tags: opencv, video, video-processing

I’ve got a cctv footage of bike robbery , video is not clear. I’m working on enhancing the video to find details about the vehicles or face  or any other information from it. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ZjiDWHZ1j-QkVKZFV4ZkV1ODA/view?usp=sharing
[image: original]original[image: histogram equalised]histogram equalised[image: CLAHE]CLAHE

What I've done till now in python opencv

1. Basic histogram equalisation  because its a night time footage.
2. Since there were bright hotspots in the film, I applied contrast limited adaptive hist equalization (CLAHE) and experimented with cliplimit 1 to 10 and grid sizes from 4 to 32.
3. I've been playing with gabor filter to reduce the headlamp flash of the bikes but not able to tune it to the right parameters.
4. Since there is some noise in the video , thought of denoising it with fastNlDenoising but with no results.
5. Since image is small I tried super resolution of the image using SeRanet [SeRanet on github](https://github.com/corochann/SeRanet).But its very slow to run on even a single image and results were not good enough to verify the face in the video. (at least on the frame I ran SeRanet over).

Any help on how can i proceed to gather more information from the video (or is it dead end by some limitations)

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('./bike_robbery.mp4')
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3.0, tileGridSize=(32,32))
count=0
sig = 1
th = 0
lm = 1.0
gm = 0.02
ps = 0;
ksize =31
gaborKernel=cv2.getGaborKernel((ksize,ksize), sig, th, lm, gm, ps);
sleeptime=0.001
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cl1 = clahe.apply(gray)
    equ = cv2.equalizeHist(gray)
    #denoise=cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(cl1,None,3,90,2)
    ths=cv2.threshold(equ, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    gab=cv2.filter2D(cl1,0 , cv2.CV_32F, gaborKernel);
    kernel = np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [-1,18,-1], [-1,-1,-1]])
    im = cv2.filter2D(equ, -1, kernel)
    res = np.hstack((gray,equ,cl1)) #stacking images side-by-side
    cv2.imwrite("./clahe_pics/frame%d.jpg" % count, cl1)
    cv2.imwrite("./hist_pics/frame%d.jpg" % count, equ)
    count = count + 1
    cv2.imshow('frame',res)
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('s'):
        sleeptime+=0.05
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('f'):
        sleeptime-=.05
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The original is too low resolution to extract faces/bike number plate from it. If it's not there, we cannot bring it magically.

Comment: Thats true Muglikar, Its just that I was trying my best and thought that may  be there might be something that can be used which I didn't know yet.

Answer (score -1):

According to the question, if you want to find the presence of human and bike you can use some classifier like human detection and also vehicle detection. for human detection you can easily find pretrained haar classifier model. and for detection bike you can train a model . as if it is a real time problem.
 But if you are concern about illumination problem, you can use LAB image and enhance L channel of the image and adjust the luminosity of the image.
for human detection you can find the model in this path of your opencv:[directory:opencv\sources\data\haarcascades](http://opencv%5Csources%5Cdata%5Chaarcascades)

Comment: Sarkar I'm working on enhancing the video rather than detecting.For illumination problem I tried it in LAB image but since its gray there was only L portion nothing in A and B channel.